# sql update syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

How do you do an update statement?

I would like to update UserID with this string theUserid and I would like to update picturepath with fileuploadpaths(string) in the same table (Pictures)

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE Pictures 
                                      SET ('" + theUserId + "','" + fileuploadpaths + "')                                  
                                    WHERE (UserID, picturepath)", cn);
```

Not sure if its

```
UPDATE Pictures 
   SET UserID = "+ theUserid +" 
       picturepath="+ fileuploadpaths +" 
 Where UserID = theUserid 
       picturepath = something already in my db?
```

**EDIT:**

Ive tryed this:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE Pictures SET picturepath ='" + fileuploadpaths + "' WHERE UserId = '" + theUserId + "')", cn);
```

but I get the error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1**

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: What is the issue that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
Update Pictures set picturepath = 'SomePath' where UserId = 'someUserId'
```

Comment: you have an extra `)` at the end, remove that - please look at @OMG Ponies answer though, you do want to use Parameters in any real world application

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE PICTURES
                                      SET userid = ?,
                                          picturepath = ?
                                    WHERE userid = ?");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theuser", theUserid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picpath", fileuploadpaths);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid);

try
{
  myConnection.executeNonQuery(cmd);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.Write("Update failed: "+e.Message);
}
```

Though the parameters have names, they are bind variables.  Meaning the value specified needs to be in the position order of the "?" placeholders, starting from the first character of the query string ("Update...").

### Reference

- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/235966
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/PassparameterstoOdbcCommand.htm

Comment: You should stress that using parameters is absolutely essentials to avoid sql injections.

Comment: @MK: I forgot before the 5 min elapsed, but yes -- that is why I provided the example I did.  Lest we forget Little Bobby Tables.

Comment: can we keep it the way Im tryin for now

Comment: @Garrith Graham no you absolutely can not keep it the way you are tring.

Answer (score 1):

You are just querying by the user ID, correct? In that case, it doesn't need to be included in your `UPDATE` clause, and the `picturepath` doesn't need to be in the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE Pictures 
   SET picturepath = '/somewhere/picture.png'
 Where UserID = 12345
```

See the [MySQL `UPDATE` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) for more.